# About a Morrey's type inequality

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ an open bounded domain and consider $B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega$ an open ball. Let $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ ($p \geq 2$). Let $s > n$ and suppose that $\int_{B_r(x_0)}  |\nabla u| ^s < \infty$.Does the following inequality is true ?

$$ |u(x) - u(x_0)| \leq  C(n,p,\Omega) |x - x_0| ^{1 - \frac{n}{s}} (\int_{B_{r}(x_0)} |\nabla u| ^s )^{1/s} $$

I am asking this because of the corolary 27.6 of this lectures (it is a general $C¹(R^n) $ case of the above inequality  ): http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Sobolev%20Inequalities.pdf

I dont need a proof , just a reference.

Any help will be apreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look in Chapter 5 of *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans. Of course the inequality requires $|x - x_0| \le r$ but the proof in Evans may have a stricter requirement.

Comment: I think the problem is whether $p^*$ greater then $s$ or not.

Comment: You're thinking of the Sobolev inequality, not Morrey's inequality.

Comment: What I was worried is that $u$ may not good enough to get in $L^s$ so that you can not apply Morrey's inequality.

Comment: But $|\nabla u| \in L^s$ is given.